# Use project or file specific spellfiles in vim

Tags: vim, latex

I just enabled spell check in vim. I like it and I know how to use it.

However, I would really like a project or even file specific spellfile as my list of accepted words. That way I can keep project (like thesis) specific words from being recognized in other projects.

When I open a Latex file in vim, I want vim to detect a particular spellfile in the Latex's file directory and load it. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can use a code snippet executed after a file has been detected to be of type `tex`.

The idea is to check for the existence of the spellfile (properly named) in the working directory and then set the spellfile accordingly.

Assuming the filetype plugin is on (`filetype plugin on`), put this in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim`:

```
let b:spellfile = expand('%:p:h').'/.vimspell.utf-8.add'
if filereadable(b:spellfile)
    let &l:spellfile = b:spellfile
    setlocal spell
    setlocal spelllang=en_us
else
   setlocal spellfile=
endif
```

This will look for a file `.vimspell.utf-8.add` in the Latex files's directory, enable spell checking and set the spellfile accordingly.

Inspired by http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Simple-way-to-add-local-spell-file-for-a-limited-set-of-filesystem-locations-td5709299.html.

Answer (score 1):

[`dialect.vim`](https://github.com/dbmrq/vim-dialect) provides an interesting alternative. The plugin binds <kbd>zG</kbd> and <kbd>zW</kbd> to `./.dialect.{encoding}.add.` file that functions similarly to the internal word list.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to create a file in the project folder, named something like `proj-local-vim-config.vim`, whose lines contain the accepted words using the following syntax `spellgood! {word}`. Of course, you may also include other project-specific Vim configurations. Here is an example:

```
set relativenumber
set spell spelllang=En
spellgood! Blockchain
spellgood! Ethereum
spellgood! JSON
...
```

I suggest to load this file manually, after Vim is launched, by entering `:source FolderPath/proj-local-vim-config.vim`